# Can't import sceneform asset: 'Imported asset was very large'

Tags: android-studio, sceneform

I'm trying to import asset with sceneform in Android studio, but I'm getting error: Imported asset was very large (16.6 x 2.6 x 5.6 m)

Is there a restriction for object size?

I tried to import small objects, and it works ok. If there is a restriction for size, what are the max values?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that asset size was not the reason why asset was not imported. It was just a warning.

Real reason was that .obj file was referencing wrong (missing) .mtl file.